# Can I access files directly after backup with Deja Dup?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I'm wanting to use Backups (Deja Dup), but I'm wondering if the files will be directly accessible off the hard disk after I've done my backup? Or do I need to perform a recovery in order to access the files?

Comment: +1 This question is unique. Both wiki and official documentation do not seem have any direct answer for this seemingly simple question from end user.

Answer (score 1):

Deja Dup backs up using duplicity as a back end. Accordingly, your backup is stored in tar-formatted files. Thus, the files you backed up are not visible or directly accessible using a file manager. One must restore the files using Deja Dup, or on the lower end, using the duplicity command line tool. Since tar is used, it is also possible to directly use the universal tar tool to extract files from the appropriate tar archive in the backup location.